# Configuring console-setup, what to do?

Tags: updates, configuration, console, encoding

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop and while the updates were being installed a window popped up:

Configuring console-setup

Encoding to use on the console : UTF-8

And it has other different options.

Which one to choose?

Comment: What are the other available options (for example, could you please add a screenshot to your post?)? And what is your system language?

Comment: On many computers, there's a dedicated key on the keyboard. Would be "PrtScn" in English for example...

Comment: Oh sorry! You can edit your original post and add the picture in it. You cannot add a picture in comment. To add a picture in a post, you can click on the little landscape on the editor, at the right side of the { } icon. From a phone I don't know but I bet there is a way to add pictures...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It seems to be regarding font choices for terminal. I found a pretty helpful site here:

Https://www.tecmint.com/change-console-fonts-in-Ubuntu-server/

I just went with the ‘UTF-8’, which I think is the default. And if you went to the site, it has a bunch of other windows that follow, I didn’t get any of those, just the first one.

Comment: UTF-8 is a character-set, not a font. Font is the style of the characters, like blocky or italic.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is the encoding du jour since 15, 20 years on Linux and even inferior OSs are using it as default, today.

In the rare cases, where it would be useful to use something else, you would probably know it.

Former encodings like iso-8859-15 for the western languages worked well for US, AUS, GB, F, D and most Western European languages, but UTF-8 is more portable and AFAIK used for Eastern European as well, and I think even Arabic, Hebrew, Korean and all the other far eastern languages.